# Launch Docker Image for MSSQL not creating a container

Tags: sql-server, linux, macos, docker, docker-for-mac

I am trying to setup MSSQL for my macOS and can't get the docker image to load and create a container. I have downloaded Docker and have it up and running

Downloaded:

```
docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

Then run via Terminal:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=<my password here> -e 
'MSSQL_PID=Express' -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server- 
linux:latest
```

I then run

```
docker ps
```

and receive, with no data

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

I am not sure where the issue occurring

Comment: Run `docker ps -a` then you will be able to see the stopped container and get the logs.

Comment: docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             
    CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES     nothing is returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Troubleshooting**

- run without `-d` command to launch the instance in attached mode.
- `docker ps -a` give you the stopped containers
- `docker logs $stoppedContainerId` give you the logs of a container

**How to resolve**

Well I tried by myself and I checked the logs >

> 2018-06-05 21:54:28.38 spid21s     ERROR: Unable to set system
>   administrator password: Password validation failed. The password does
>   not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is too
>   short. The password must be at least 8 characters..

I assume you have the same problem because it's working with a strong password.